# How to calculate overall-mean for subsets in R

Tags: r

Assume I have longitudinal data (e.g. 21 countries' gdp over 5 years) with 2 variables of the same scale. data is sorted as follows

| Country-year | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA-1 | 50 | 2 |
| USA-2 | 47 | 1.5 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| USA-5 | 52 | 1.9 |
| UK-1 | 63 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| UK-5 | 41 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... |

```
n = 21
m = 5
N = n * m
set.seed(123)
x <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, rep(0,2), diag(2))
```

I want to do two things:

- First, calculate the mean country-wise
- Second, calculate the mean year-wise

For the first task, I have the following code

```
x_barbar <- NULL
k = 1
for(i in 1:n){
 x_barbar[i] <- mean(x[k:(k + (m - 1)), ])
 k = k + m
}
```

How can I optimize my code for the first task and figure out a code to do the second task?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the column means of odd values and even values?? I really have a hard time understanding what you want

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the column means of odd values and even values?? I really have a hard time understanding what you want. Set the seed then do an example by hand of just 5 rows with the expected results.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just edited the question. I hope my question is clear now. Pardon my English.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate mean of odd/even rows you can use vector recycling.

```
mean_odd <- mean(x[c(TRUE, FALSE), ])
mean_even <- mean(x[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])
```

---

For the updated dataset we can separate country and year column and calculate mean.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- df %>% separate(`Country-year`, c('Country', 'Year'), sep = '-') 

country_mean <- data %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(across(c(x1, x2), mean))

year_mean <- data %>% group_by(Year) %>%summarise(across(c(x1, x2), mean))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just updated my question in order to make it clear. Please have a look.

Comment: @MOHAMMED For your updated question I think it would be easier if we separate year and country value in different column. See. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use `tapply`

For example the first case

```
tapply(x, (row(x)+1)%/%2, mean)
```

For the second case:

```
tapply(x, row(x)%%2, mean)
```